# WebDriver opens Microsoft Word application making the browser window go back / outfocus. How do I get my browser focus back?

Tags: selenium, ms-word, webdriver, focus, toggle

During Automation, certain link has to be clicked and it opens a microsoft word document which is a desktop application window. this is making my driver window go out focus. However, remaining code is running in the back-end, but how do we minimise this word window ( i know this is not possible as word is a windows application)  but atleast how can I bring my driver window to front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use Robot by java to do CTRL+TAB (this should switch you back to previous window)
try this

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
robot.delay(100);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
```

Comment: This was just like pressing alt and tab on keyboard, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out `windowUtils.killByProcessName(“winword.exe”);`
Does the job. We just need to import selenium windows util jar for it.